# 2-dimensional array name 1st element

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

C Programming in One Hour a Day has this quote:

> As with a one-dimensional array, the name of a multidimensional array is a pointer to the first array element.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int m[2][4];

int main() {
    printf("%p\n", m);        // 1
    printf("%p\n", &(m[0]));  // 2
    printf("%p\n", m[0]);     // 3
    printf("%p\n", &m[0][0]); // 4
}
```

This prints the same value for all the statements. Based on the quote, it makes sense that 1 == 2 and 3 == 4. But I don't understand how 2 == 3. How could the address of `m[0]` be the same as `m[0]`?

Comment: Because, that is how it is implemented and because of which `int *p = malloc(n * sizeof(int))` works.
Try printing `&m`, it'll also result in the same. Because for the case of an array, all these are not actually implemented and doesn't occupy memory, but can be still used and considered as pointers pointing to an array( or address )

Comment: OT: The conversion specifier `%p` is defined for a `void`-pointer only, so the code should look like this `printf("%p\n", (void*) m);`. Same for the other three calls to `printf()`. Else undefined behaviour is invoked.

Comment: Dear lord, in how many ways was this question asked already?

Comment: "As with a one-dimensional array, the name of a multidimensional array is a pointer to the first array element." --> No.  An array is not a pointer.  An array coverts to a pointer of the first element in select cases, yet `m` is still an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a two dimensional (or any dimensional) array is allocated, **it just occupies the memory for its elements** (memory is not allocated to the array name or any other array elements like `m[0]` and `m[1]` in your case, which acts like const pointers).

Because there will not be any physical memory allocated to those (actually not even needed), you'll get the same address when tried to print those. In your case,
as it is a 2 dimensional array, as `m` points to `m[0]` which in turn points to `m[0][0]`, fetching address of all these will give the same values ( also for `m[1]` and `m[1][0]`).

**For better understanding, see this (this is how it will be if you print those)

```
      _____         _____         _____
     |0x100|  -->  |0x100|  -->  |value|
0x100|_____|  0x100|_____|  0x100|_____|
       m            m[0]         m[0][0]
```

*`value` is the value of m[0][0]

Here,
  `m` and `m[0]` acts like pointers but are not physically implemented (doesn't occupy memory) and the compiler handles how to treat those.

*Though I have shown that `0x100` contains `0x100` for `m` and `m[0]`, `0x100` actually contains the data/value of `m[0][0]`, but if you do any operations that is how the compiler treats them.

**And because of that, `int *p = malloc(n * sizeof(int))` this is possible with the difference that `p` now occupies memory which points to starting address of array. If you consider `p` as `int const *p`, you can treat it like a normal array without dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 3):

An array *only* contains data, it does not contain anything else. This data has an address where it starts at - which is the address of the first element.

"the name of a multidimensional array is a pointer to the first array element" is an over-simplification and not really correct. Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.

However, the name of an array (of any dimension), whenever used in an expression, yields a temporary pointer to the first element of the array. This is often referred to as "the array decays into a pointer".

Now, the only thing that's different between those lines is the type of the pointer:

1. The array of type `int[2][4]` decays into a pointer to the first element. The first element in the 2D array is a 1D array of type `int [4]`. A pointer to such an array is an *array pointer*, `int (*)[4]`.
2. `&m[0]` gives the address of the first element, the address of the first 1D array. So this is completely equivalent to 1).
3. `m[0]` gives the first element, still a 1D array. Which decays into a pointer to its first element. The first element of a `int [4]` is an `int`, so we get a pointer to that, a `int*`.
4. `&m[0][0]` gives the pointer to the first array's first element, an `int*`. Equivalent to 3).

All of these pointer types will have the same address, simply because the 2D array starts at the same address as its first item, the 1D array. Which in turn starts at the same address as its first item, the first integer.

The various different pointer types are just high-level language syntax. Those types are not something that persists in the machine code, where everything is just raw addresses.

Answer (score 0):

First dimention will store address of subarray (row).

E.g. you have `m[2]﻿[4]`, so `m[0]` evaluates to address of first row containing elements from `m[0]﻿[0]` to `m[0]﻿[3]` and `m[1]` evaluates to address of second row contains elements from `m[1]﻿[0]` to `m[1]﻿[3]`.

If you try to print `m[0]` and `m[1]` you will see address difference is total size of row at `m[0]` bytes apart.

Comment: Good. Now for the other inaccuracy: "*m[0] stores address of first row*" it actually *does not* store it. What happens is called `m[0]` "decays to" the address of the first row.

Comment: I agree the value m[0] is not read from storage, rather its calculated when referred